# Mockito Content Type Not Set

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am writing unit test for Controller.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public class EmployeeController {

  ....
}
```

Junit with Mickito -

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(EmployeeController.class)
public class EmployeeControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private EmployeeService service;

  @Mock
  private EmployeeResponse response;

  .....
  .....

}
```

Below are the dependency -

```
springBootVersion = '2.3.3.RELEASE'
dependencyManagementVersion = '1.0.8.RELEASE'
```

Always I am getting below error - `Content type not set`

Comment: Any @Test method ??

Comment: Please add the test method that is failing. This [MockMvc Guide](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/) might help you getting started with testing your controller.